# Uploading PERN stack on AZURE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express, visual-studio-code

I have made a basic todo list React app (PERN stack), and can run it locally on my computer. I have not added any files (docker or web config) aside from a client folder and server(frontend) folder(backend) following this tutorial

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldYcgPKEZC8
Github code: https://github.com/ousecTic/pern-todo-app

I am now uploading this application onto an Azure Web app, via a GitHub repository linked onto VS code. Deployment goes fine, but the site does not run properly.

Here are the errors I am receiving from Azure's end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6GGh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGuwM.png)

What node modules or other things could I be missing?

Thanks

Comment: try changing the consumption plan to premium

Comment: Thanks, my app is a small so the plan shouldn't be necessary. However I did find out that I was uploading the back + front end at the same time, causing the issue, also find directly deploying is more reliable than using github deployment

Answer (score 0):

The issue to my problem turned out to be that I was uploading my front end and back end at the same time, only uploading my front end worked. Also found in my case that deploying directly is more reliable than deploying via a connection on Github.